# MikTeX Package Manager missing amssymb package

Tags: amsmath, miktex, amssymb

I installed new copy (released on Nov 15, 2016) of `MikTeX` on my `Windows 10` from [here](https://miktex.org/2.9/setup) and noticed that when I search in MiKTeX `Package Manager` it's missing `amssymb` package. When I search for keyword ams I see packages shown below. Is amssymb part of any of the following packages? If not, how can I install amssymb?
[image]

Comment: It's in `amsfonts`.

Comment: @Bernard -- make that an answer, please.

Comment: @barbara beeton: done, milady!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `amssymb` package is part of of the `amsfonts` bundle.

If you right-click on a package in MiKTeX Package Manager, and choose the `Files` tab, you obtain the list of all files in the package:

[image]